# Does a function parameter in C always have the same memory address?

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameters

Okay, so C is pass-by-value, which means a copy of the variable is used instead of the original variable for the parameter, right? So, will that copy always have the same memory address? Consider this code:

```
void test(int *ptr) {   
    printf("&ptr: %p\n", &ptr);
    printf("ptr: %p\n", ptr);
    printf("*ptr: %d\n\n", *ptr);
}

int main() {
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5;
    test(&a);
    test(&b);
    test(&c);
    test(&d);
    test(&e);

    return 0;
}
```

The output I get from this code is this:

```
&ptr: 0x7fff70536728
ptr: 0x7fff7053674c
*ptr: 1

&ptr: 0x7fff70536728
ptr: 0x7fff70536750
*ptr: 2

&ptr: 0x7fff70536728
ptr: 0x7fff70536754
*ptr: 3

&ptr: 0x7fff70536728
ptr: 0x7fff70536758
*ptr: 4

&ptr: 0x7fff70536728
ptr: 0x7fff7053675c
*ptr: 5
```

My gut feeling was "no". It is my understanding that the `ptr` doesn't exist outside the code block of `test()`. So, why is `&ptr` the same for all five function calls?

Comment: It is not guaranteed to be the same. You are observing unspecified behavior. (You can see the address change if you call it from another function in addition to main.)

Comment: and it may not exhibit this behavior at all, even without an intervening function call. depending on the implementation on a particular machine.

Comment: @AndyzSmith also depending on how the compiler decides to implement it.  :)

Comment: @jmstoker i wonder what happens if you do this on ideone.com?

Comment: @AndyzSmith The behavior is the same.  I'm not surprised though.  It would be silly for the compiler not to see that the local pointer is reused and just reuse it.  After the code is compiled everything is global, so why not just reuse an address instead of creating a new one each time.

Comment: @jmstoker yeah, i'm just thinking that you probably find a major vendor compiler that does something really nonintuitive with these.  something really weird,like cause a virtual memory page fault and you always get address zero or something.

Comment: I _think_ that when a compiler sees the `&ptr` in the `test()` function,it realizes that `ptr` needs to be passed as a variable in memory and may not optimize by passing via a register or possible putting the entire function into in-line code.  Thus if `printf("&ptr: %p\n", &ptr);` is removed, you do not know if the new code is even using a memory location  or register for `ptr`.  Of course looking as compiled code would show the result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&ptr` is the same because `ptr` is a local variable within `test()`. Since you're calling `test()` five times in succession without anything intervening, it's just being given the same address on the stack every time it's called (note, this isn't in any way *required* by C - it's just how your machine is doing it, and how it would usually happen).

If you called a second function which then itself called `test()`, you would not get the same output for `&ptr`, since that space on the stack in which `ptr` was previously residing is now being used by the intervening function call.

For instance:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(int *ptr) {
    printf("&ptr: %p\n", (void *) &ptr);
    printf("ptr: %p\n", (void *) ptr);
    printf("*ptr: %d\n\n", *ptr);
}

void test_test(void) {
    int a = 1;
    test(&a);
}

int main() {
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5;

    test(&a);
    test(&b);
    test(&c);
    test(&d);
    test(&e);
    test_test();

    return 0;
}
```

yields:

```
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$ ./ptrtest
&ptr: 0x7fff39f79068
ptr: 0x7fff39f7909c
*ptr: 1

&ptr: 0x7fff39f79068
ptr: 0x7fff39f79098
*ptr: 2

&ptr: 0x7fff39f79068
ptr: 0x7fff39f79094
*ptr: 3

&ptr: 0x7fff39f79068
ptr: 0x7fff39f79090
*ptr: 4

&ptr: 0x7fff39f79068
ptr: 0x7fff39f7908c
*ptr: 5

&ptr: 0x7fff39f79048
ptr: 0x7fff39f7906c
*ptr: 1

paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$
```

and you can see that `&ptr` is different on the last call, which is made via `test_test()`.